# Reading till EOF in Java when using Fast Input in JAVA

Tags: java, class, input, file-io, io

I am solving a [question](https://www.codechef.com/DEC17/problems/CPLAY) for which input size is very large and Scanner and BufferedReader ways of input will give Time Limit Exceeded result. So I use an user defined fast input class to get faster input. The catch this time is that we need to read input till end of file. The class which I am using does not have a hasNext() as in Scanner class which is useful when reading input till EOF. How can I tackle this problem?

[FastReader class:](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fast-io-in-java-in-competitive-programming/)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main
{
    static class FastReader
    {
        BufferedReader br;
        StringTokenizer st;


    public FastReader()
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

    String next()
    {
        while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements())
        {
            try
            {
                st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            }
            catch (IOException  e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return st.nextToken();
    }

    int nextInt()
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    long nextLong()
    {
        return Long.parseLong(next());
    }

    double nextDouble()
    {
        return Double.parseDouble(next());
    }

    String nextLine()
    {
        String str = "";
        try
        {
            str = br.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring end of stream. Solution: don't.

Comment: @EJP How can I take end of stream into account? What function should I add to the FastReader class and how?